# Cloudera VM- Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Although similar question were available on SO this one is on Cloudera cdh4 VM which I on use on 64bit Windows for learning purpose.
 I get this error while performing Word count map reduce at this point `FileInputFormat.setInputPaths()` method.
PS: I am total noob to hadoop. So the previous similar questions didn't do much help for this specific situation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add required jar files to you project . ? If not please add jar files from /usr/lib/hadoop/client .

Or Use training project in eclipse which comes by default with cloudera vm.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out.I missed a part of code. Now I seem to get **PrivilegedActionException** saying that the file:/user/cloudera/input cannot be found.